# Can't send emails using Laravel 5.0.33

Tags: php, email, laravel, phpmailer

I was trying to send emails using the code below:

```
'driver' => 'smtp',
'host' => 'a2plcpnl0296.prod.iad2.secureserver.net;a2plcpnl0296.prod.iad2.secureserver.net',
'port' => 587,
'from' => ['address' => 'contact@theventuregame.com', 'name' => 'The Venture Game TM'],
'encryption' => 'tls',
'username' => 'xxx',
'password' => 'yyy',
'pretend' => false,
```

When I try to send email using these conf the error shows as below:
Connection could not be established with host a2plcpnl0296.prod.iad2.secureserver.net;a2plcpnl0296.prod.iad2.secureserver.net [php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. #0].

I think I know what the issue is, to add SMTP Authentication to true, but I just dont know where can I put that parameter.

On the other hand I have this code which works perfectly fine, but I would want the Laravel one config as it is more clean:

```
        $this->mail = new PHPMailer;
        $this->mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $this->mail->Host = 'a2plcpnl0286.prod.iad2.secureserver.net;a2plcpnl0286.prod.iad2.secureserver.net';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $this->mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $this->mail->Username = 'xxx';                 // SMTP username
        $this->mail->Password = 'yyy';                           // SMTP password
        $this->mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $this->mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

        $this->mail->From = 'contact@theventuregame.com';
        $this->mail->FromName = 'The Venture Game TM';
```

As you can see on the above code I have this:

```
$this->mail->SMTPAuth = true;
```

Wich I think if I would have it declared somewhere in Laravel would make it work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an auth problem - it's not getting that far.

The `Host` property is documented [here](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#property_Host) and the `Host` string is split on `;`. You have listed the same server twice in your `Host` property. Try just setting it to `a2plcpnl0286.prod.iad2.secureserver.net`. Beyond that, set `SMTPDebug = 4` and you'll get verbose output telling you about the connection.

You should check that that email server is actually accessible - how to do that is covered in [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

Make sure you're using the [latest PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) too.

I also note you're on GoDaddy, who have notoriously bad email support.

Comment: Sorry for late confirm.. it worked like a charm :) had to remove the rest of the string after ";"